# Accessing dictionary values in django templates

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-templates

Please help me in displaying the values of dictionary in django templates. I tried google to find out, but could not get the solution.

Below is the Model

```
class Ride(models.Model): 
    type = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    add_source = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='source')
    add_destination = models.ForeignKey(Address, related_name='destination')
    ride_comment = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=140,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ride_comment

class Driver(models.Model):
    ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    drv_carseats = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_id.username
```

View

```
for ride in result_list:
        if ride.type:
            driver = Driver.objects.get(ride_id = ride)
            userList[ride.pk] = driver.user_id.username
            print 'driver', driver.user_id.username, userList[ride.pk]
 return render_to_response('rides/search.html', {'result_list':result_list,'userList':userList}, context )
```

And here is my template code

```
{% for result in result_list %}
     {% if result %}
         <a href="/rides/ridedetails/{{ result.pk }}">{{ userList[result.pk] }}</a>
         <em>{{ result.add_source }}</em>
         <em>{{ result.add_destination }}</em>
         <em>{{ result.ride_comment }}</em>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am getting the following error

> TemplateSyntaxError at /rides/search/
>
> Could not parse the remainder: '[result.pk]' from 'userList[result.pk]'

Answer (score 0):

you should write a django custom filter for this.

create a file name get_dict_val.py inside your app..

```
project
   -app
      -templatetags
          __init__.py
          get_dict_val.py
```

Now in get_dict_val.py

```
@register.filter
def get_item(dictionary, key):
    return dictionary.get(key)
```

In template
add this as first line write..

```
{% load get_dict_val %}
```

now replace in your code in template

```
<a href="/rides/ridedetails/{{ result.pk }}">{{ userList|get_item:result.pk }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create dictionary to access drivers at the template level, you can [follow the relationship backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward) as `Driver` model has the foreign key for `Ride` model:

```
{% for result in result_list %}
     {% if result %}
         {% with result.driver_set.all as drivers %}
             {% for driver in drivers %}
                 <a href="/rides/ridedetails/{{ result.pk }}">{{ driver.user_id }}</a>
             {% endfor %}
         {% endwith %}
         <em>{{ result.add_source }}</em>
         <em>{{ result.add_destination }}</em>
         <em>{{ result.ride_comment }}</em>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is good to specify the [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) for `ForeignKey` as it makes life easier to access objects:

```
ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride, related_name='drivers')
```

Then you can do:

```
ride = Ride.objects.get(id='some_id')
drivers = ride.drivers.all()
```